# Релятивный фильтр PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый день, пишу для сайта умный фильтр по аналогии Яндекс.Маркета.
Собственно уже который день озадачился вопросом реализация релятивного фильтра.

Что имеем:

Динамическую форму: (Форма генерируется автоматически, но для наглядности вставил HTML)

```
<form method="get" action="">
<div>
<label>Asus</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Asus">
<label>Acer</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Acer">
<label>Lenovo</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="Lenovo">
</div>
<div>
<label>2015</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="2015">
<label>2014</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="2014">
<label>2013</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="filter[]" value="2013">
</div>
<button>Искать</button>
</form>
```

После сабмита формы имеется url следующего вида:

```
site.com?filter=Asus&filter=2015
```

Так же имеем таблицы в базе данных:

```
products (id, title)
products_to_filter (id, product_id, filter_id)
```

Сам обработчик выглядит следующим образом (P.S фреймворк Laravel)

```
Выборка соответствующих фильтров.
$filter[] = explode(',', $request->input('filter');
$filters = DB::table('products_to_filter')->whereIn('id', $filter)
->get()
->all();
foreach($filters as $row) {$filterArray[] = $row->product_id;}
Выборка продуктов:
$products = DB::table('products')->whereIn('id', $filterArray)->get()->all();
```

Собственно моя проблема заключается в следующем, фильтр работает, но не совсем так как мне нужно, тобишь при фильтрации, он должен результаты уменьшать, а он же наоборот ищет более углубленно, и как следствие увеличивает кол-во результатов. Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 3):

Вы неправильно формируете `$filterArray` - слишком это все просто. Сейчас условие которое вы получаете звучит так:

> Выбрать `product_id`, которые соответствуют хотя бы одному выбранному пункту

Если вы поменяете логику на

> Выбрать `product_id`, которые соответствуют всем выбранным пунктам

то это тоже будет ошибкой (ну ведь не может же быть у одного и того же продукта производителем и Acer и Asus). В саму идею построения формы вкралась ошибка. Пункты (фильтры) нужно собирать в группы (производитель, год выпуска и т. д). И логика построения `$filterArray` должна звучать так:

> Выбрать `product_id`, которые соответствуют всем выбранным группам фильтров. Соответствие группе - это соответствие хотя бы одному из фильтров группы.

**Дополнено**
Я не очень силен в Laravel но идея вот такая:

```
// Допустим получаем из формы массив вот такого вида
$filtersgroup = array(
    'manufacturer' => array(21, 22, 23),
    'year'         => array(37, 48),
    'type'         => array(51, 54, 59),
);

// Для построения запроса нам понадобится иметь номера таблиц, для связи с первой
$ix = 1;
foreach ($filtersgroup as $filtersId) {
    $alias = 'pf' . $ix;
    if (1 == $ix) {
        $query = DB::table('product_to_filter AS pf1');
    } else {
        // Каждую последующую таблицу связываем с первой
        $query = $query->join('product_to_filter AS ' . $alias, 
            'pf1.product_id', 
            '=', 
            $alias . '.product_id');
    }
    // Добавляем условие для каждой группы
    $query = $query->whereIn($alias . '.product', $filtersId);
    $ix += 1;
}

// Выполняем запрос, получаем список product_id
$filterArr = $query->select('pf1.product_id')->distinct()->pluck('product_id')}
```

В принципе можно добавить первой таблицу `products` и получать в результате запроса уже готовый список "продуктов"

Comment: Можете продемонстрировать алгоритм правильной постройки?

Comment: @asd, Дополнил ответ